# Repeated Points and R^2

Tags: regression, r-squared

I am taking a Linear Regression class and am a bit confused with  $R^2$ and repeat points (i.e. more than one *y* value at the same *x* value). The book explains that when there are repeat points, $R^2$ can never be exactly equal to 1 because the model cannot explain the variability related to "pure" error. I don't understand what "pure error" means in this context - the topic is covered in a later chapter which we didn't cover yet. I ask because I am trying to do the following problem (from Introduction to Linear Regression by Montgomery, Peck and Vinning):

Prove that the maximum value of $R^2$ is less than 1 if the data contain repeated (different) observations on y at the same value of x

In general if $R^2$ is given by $$1-\frac{SS_{RES}}{SS_{T}}$$ then $R^2$ would only be one if $SS_{RES}$ is zero. Therefore, if $SS_{RES}$ is not zero, then the maximum value of $R^2$ would have to be less than 1. Also $R^2$ would move in the same direction as the variability in *x*. Repeated points would suggest less variability.

Is this question trying to throw me off or am I missing something here? And does "pure" error here signify something? Furthermore, is there some specific treatment of data containing repeat observations?

I would appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Note that all you need to do is show that the error sum of squares is positive.  If you have distinct values of $x$ but for some $x$ you have more than one value of $y$, is it possible that all the points fall on a single line?  Also by pure error they mean the $\epsilon$ term in the equation $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \epsilon$.  This is a term that's considered noise which no model can account for.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - but what about the word "maximum" in the question - by showing that the model error sum of squares is positive, how is that showing that the max is less than 1? To answer your question, no..they can't fall on a line. so pure error is another name for residual?

Comment: Since $R^2 = 1 - SSR / SST$ and we know that $SSR > 0$ necessarily, then $R^2 < 1$ no matter what.  It doesn't matter if it's been maximized.  Yes, pure error refers to the error term of the "true" model.  These are errors in prediction that will be made even if you know the exact data generating process.